# How to setup YARN with Spark in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I need to setup spark cluster (1 Master and 2 slaves nodes) on centos7 along with resource manager as YARN. I am new to all this and still exploring. Can somebody share me detailed steps of setting up Spark with Yarn in cluster mode.
Afterwards i have to integrate Livy too(an open source REST interface for using Spark from anywhere).
Inputs are welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YARN is part of Hadoop. So, a Hadoop installation is necessary to run Spark on YARN.
Check out the page on the [Hadoop Cluster Setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html).

Then you can utilize the [this documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) to learn about Spark on YARN.

Another method to quickly learn about Hadoop, YARN and Spark is to utilize Cloudera Distribution of Hadoop (CDH). Read the [CDH 5 Quick Start Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Quick-Start/CDH5-Quick-Start.html).

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using the similar setup in aws. AWS EMR is costly hence 
we setup our own cluster using ec2 machines with the help of [Hadoop Cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/hadoop). The cookbook supports multiple distributions, however we choose HDP.

The setup included following.

1. Master Setup

   1. Spark (Along with History server)
   2. Yarn Resource Manager
   3. HDFS Name Node
   4. Livy server
2. Slave Setup

   1. Yarn Node Manager
   2. HDFS Data Node

More information on manually installing can be found in [HDP Documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_command-line-installation/content/index.html)

You can see the part of that automation in [here](https://github.com/Prasannasaraf/Spark-on-Yarn).